# Android: Get MotionEvent within onListItemClick

Tags: android, listview, event-handling, listactivity

I have a ListActivity and I want react to 
onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
.

But I also want to know whether the user clicked on the left or the right side of the screen.
Is there any changes I can get the MotionEvent from within the onListItemclicked-method.

I have a ListView. In every line there is a Name on the left and a average-vote on the right. When the user clicks in a row on the left I want to load an Activity that shows information about the name. When the user clicks on the right side of a row I want to load an Activity that lets the user vote on the name. I would like to use onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) for getting the row I'm in as it is so easy. But how can I know whether the user clicked on the left or the right.

Can I ask some object for the currently processed MotionEvent?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What about setting an `OnClickListener` for both the left view and the right view? If necessary, you could pad the views so that they cover more of the row than they currently do. Then you would still receive the `onListItemClick` when the click occurs in a "neutral" area.

Comment: I have just one `ListView` that can give me an `onListItemClick`. But within every item of the list I have four `TextView`s (2 on the left above eachother, 2 on the right above eachother). Writing this, I'm wondering what I get as `View v` from `onListItemClick`. Will I get the some view that reflects the whole item in the list or will I get one of my `TextView`s so I can infer the side, that was pressed, from that?

Comment: You can actually set an `OnClickListener` individually for each of your TextViews